# Can I expire access token in OAuth2.0 in 30 mins?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I know the expiration time of access token is 60 mins. But I would like to expire it in 30 mins So Do OAuth has any endpoint to expire token?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) nor none of the other specifications related to OAuth2 imposes a 1 hour access token lifetime.

The value `3600` in the RFC6749 is just an example given in the possible responses sent by the authorization server.
In the [section 4.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2), the `expires_in` parameter is described as follow:

> RECOMMENDED.  The lifetime in seconds of the access token.  **For example, the value "3600" denotes that the access token will expire in one hour** from the time the response was generated. If omitted, the authorization server SHOULD provide the expiration time via other means or document the default value.

To conclude: reguarding your security policy, if it makes sense to issue an access token with 1 minute lifetime, then nothing prevent you from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 itself doesn't give a client the possibility to set a custom token expiration time, but your concrete implementation may have some way of doing it. The closest think you can do is to revoke a token using the `/revoke` endpoint described in the [OAuth 2.0 Token Revocation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009). But by revoking a token other tokens or a session can get revoked too:

> Depending on the authorization server's revocation policy, the
> revocation of a particular token may cause the revocation of related
> tokens and the underlying authorization grant.  If the particular
> token is a refresh token and the authorization server supports the
> revocation of access tokens, then the authorization server SHOULD also
> invalidate all access tokens based on the same authorization grant
> (see Implementation Note).  If the token passed to the request is an
> access token, the server MAY revoke the respective refresh token as
> well.

Comment: Hi Ján Halaša. I wrote an answer too because I disagree with the first sentence of your answer. From my understanding, there is no obligation to have a 1 hour access token lifetime. The `expires_in` only depends on the security policy of the authorization server.
Hoping both answers will help Lalit Kushwah.

Comment: Thank you Florent for the comment, I agree with it. I think I just didn't write  the first part of my answer well enough to be clearly understandable. I meant it from the standpoint of a client (who cannot influence the token expiration time), so I updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent. I now agree with the new version of your answer. You focused on the client side while I focused on the server one. The question is not clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

yes in short you just have to change  **AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan** property to the time you want . when you are configuring change the value .